# Facebook Marketing API Placement asset customization asset_feed_spec error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'v been trying to automatically generate ads with different content based on the placements (facebook-feed, messenger-story). I'v been trying to follow the documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-creative/placement-asset-customization#asset-feed

But for some reason, it returns an error saying that the entire object_story_spec is wrong. But this probably has to do something with my asset_feed_spec, because it's the only thing I have been changing.

```
object_story_spec param is invalid
Object story spec is ill formed. Maybe missing Page ID or creative details, or invalid fields exist
```

Have anyone tried to do this before? Or is there any way for me to get a clearer error message?

Here is the code I'm using when trying to create the creative.

```
$creative->setData([
   AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION_TYPE => $callToAction,
   AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image_hash,
   AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
   AdCreativeFields::ASSET_FEED_SPEC => $this->getAssetFeedSpec($post_message, $link_url, $headline, $image_hash, $description)
]);
```

To make it a bit more readable, I created a function that creates the different Asset feed specifications. To understand it a bit better, see the example in the documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-creative/placement-asset-customization#supported-fields

```
public function getAssetFeedSpec($post_message, $link_url, $headline, $image_hash, $description) {
    return [
      'images' => [
        [
          'hash' => $image_hash
        ]
      ],
      'bodies' => [
        [
          'adlabels' => [
              [
                'name' => 'labelfirst',
              ]
          ],
          'text' => $post_message
        ],
        [
          'adlabels' => [
              [
                'name' => 'labelsecond',
              ]
          ],
          'text' => $headline
        ]
      ],
      'titles' => [
        [
          'text' => $headline
        ]
      ],
      'descriptions' => [
        [
          'text' => $description
        ]
      ],
      'ad_formats' => [
        'SINGLE_IMAGE'
      ],
      'call_to_action_types' => [
        'LEARN_MORE'
      ],
      'link_urls' => [
        [
          'website_url' => $link_url
        ]
      ],
      'videos' => [],
      'asset_customization_rules' => $this->getAssetCustomizationRules()
    ];
}
```

I also separated the  asset_customization_rules to make that a bit more understandable.

```
public function getAssetCustomizationRules() {
    return [
        [
            'customization_spec' => [
                'publisher_platforms' => [
                    'facebook',
                    'instagram',
                    'audience_network',
                    'messenger'
                ],
                'facebook_positions' => [
                    'feed',
                ],
                'instagram_positions' => [
                    'stream'
                ],
                'audience_network_positions' => [
                    'classic'
                ]
            ],
            'body_label' => [
                'name' => 'labelfirst'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'customization_spec' => [
                'publisher_platforms' => [
                    'messenger'
                ],
                'messenger_positions' => [
                    'stream'
                ]
            ],
            'body_label' => [
                'name' => 'labelsecond'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate creative, you need to pass object_story_spec with valid page_id just like below,

```
{
"object_story_spec": {
    "page_id": "10506210208xxx"
},
"asset_feed_spec": {
    "videos": [
        {
            "adlabels": [
                {
                    "name": "placement_asset_3667064314xxx"
                }
            ],
            "video_id": "3667064314xxx"
        },
..
```

It should work after providing a valid page_id, It's working for me.

Comment: Can you provide any reference for setting this for carousel format?